# Get annotation information from JAX-RS annotation

Tags: java, scala, java-8, jersey, jax-rs

I´m using JAX-RS Request filter where my endpoint annotation @Country contains some information of the country that my filter need to do some stuff.

```
@GET
@Path("/country")
@Country("ESP")
public Future<String> countryResource(Future<String> future) throws Exception {
```

So now my filter is invoked since this method contains the same filter

```
@Priority(3)
@Primary
@Provider
@Country
class CountryFilter extends ContainerRequestFilter {

    override def filter(context: ContainerRequestContext): Unit = {
        //Here I need to get the "ESP" from the endpoint annotation
    }
}
```

I'm not an expert of `JAX-RS` but I doubt is possible to know what information of the annotation of my endpoint has, but since the filter only is invoked in case a method add the annotation as well, I was just wondering if there was any magic here.

For now I was just using `reflexion` to look for all methods annotated as `@Country` and whose `@Path` it would be the same as the `context.getUtiInfo` of the `ContainerRequestContext`.

Is this the best and most efficient way to do it?.

Regards.

Comment: Inject [ResourceInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27863284/2587435) to get current class and method. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Brilliant and elegant solution!, thanks you my good sir!

Comment: Im just going to close it as a duplicate because even though the questions were not exactly the same, the same solution covered both questions. Unless you want to write an answer, then I'll reopen it.